# Delete frame in video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video at 24 frames per second. I understand that means that 24 images will appear in 1 second in a row? Is that wrong? If that is true, can each image be deleted and edited in 24 images that appear on that 1 second? and can ffmpeg do that? This is just an idea I suddenly thought of to be able to interfere more deeply with an existing video. Anyone think like that?

Comment: maybe. sometimes. sometimes. yes. at least one.

Comment: according to you it is true or false

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 24 frames per second means there are 24 images (each image is a frame) in each second. ffmpeg can extract that sequence of frames. ffmpeg can assemble a sequence of frames to create a video. You are free to edit/photoshop/replace the frames in between those two steps; ffmpeg can't prevent that and won't be bothered by it (so long as the image dimensions remain the same as all the other frames).